# optimization of functions with many input parameters in C

Tags: c, performance, optimization, parameter-passing

I have a function which is inside a big loop in my code, and it occupies most of the cpu time:

```
inline void myfunc(double v1, ... , double vN){
  ...
  (general, complex, multiline manipulation of v1 .. vN)
  ...
  res = v1;
}
```

in which `res` is a global variable and the number N of passed arguments is about 20. I've tried to optimize the function calling by passing the variable pointers:

```
inline void myfunc(double *v1, ... , double *vN){
  ...
  (general, complex, multiline manipulation of *v1 .. *vN)
  ...
  res = *v1;
}
```

and then of course calling it by `myfunc(&v1, ..., &vN)`. I assume that in the first case at each call the function must create local v1..vN variables, while in the second case it doesn't need to.
I found that both versions work (duh!) but actually I get no speed up at all with the second case. Why is that?

Comment: Instead of passing 20 arguments, could you pass a single pointer to a struct that contains the arguments?

Comment: by taking addresses you're more likely to prevent the compiler from making optimisations.

Comment: Are all your parameters `double`?

Comment: Means the issue is in `(general, complex, multiline manipulation of *v1 .. *vN)`. Passing primitive types by pointers don't offer any tangible performance benefit.

Comment: Did you try changing the function to take *references* rather than pointers?

Comment: @RandomDavis : actually no, I'm passing very different variables of different type, here simplified in v1..vN

Comment: @RichardHodges : Why? How optimization would take advantage of creating ~20 variables at each call?

Comment: the code is actually in C, which I think doesn't have pass by reference, it can only be emulated using pointers.

Comment: @cipper the compiler is under no obligation to actually pass any arguments if it can optimise your expressed intent into simpler code with the same outcome. The more simply you express your intent, the easier the optimiser's job (assuming you have enabled it). Google the as-if rule.

Comment: Don't include the C++ tag if your code is C; don't include the C tag if your code is C++.  The languages have some parts in common, but modern C++ programs are radically different from modern C programs and vice versa.

Comment: Yes Jonathan, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what you're doing:

- In the first version of `myfunc`, you're passing **N** `double` parameters by value, making **N** copies of `sizeof(double)`.
- In the second version, you're passing **N** `double*` parameters by value, then accessing them. You're making **N** copies of `sizeof(double*)`, then following a pointer indirection. Passing pointers/references also prevents the compiler from performing more aggressive optimizations.

In short, **the second version is doing more work than the first one**. If you see no difference, it's likely that the compiler was able to optimize the indirections/copies away.

You can use the awesome [**gcc.godbolt.org**](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) website to easily compare the generated assembly for both versions, on multiple compilers.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see it.
Is there any way to speed up the call?

Comment: @cipper: have you tried storing the values in an array and passing a pointer to the array? *(Unrelated)* - have you considered parallelism for your computations?

Comment: As commented above, I'm actually passing very different variables of different type, here simplified in v1..vN. But I'll think about it. Thank you.
The code is already openmp parallel.

Comment: @cipper: ah, sorry. How about storing the variables in an `std::tuple` *(or a `class`/`struct`)* and passing a reference to that instead? It would avoid copying every single element.

Comment: I'd like to keep this code in plain C... however I'll keep the suggestion in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: @cipper You can use a `struct` in plain C

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying a `double` into the function as an argument, you are copying a pointer.

A pointer is of `size_t` which is exactly as `double` if you are on `x64` (`8 bytes` each) architecture.

More than that:

- Now you need to *dereference* the passed arguments.
- You need to *get a pointer to them* before passing them to the method.
- ***You are losing possible compiler optimizations*** in the calculation itself which is probably more expensive than the argument passing anyway.

If this method contains a manipulation that takes a long time then ***optimize the manipulation itself*** instead of the argument passing.

You didn't provide enough information to help you optimize the function body itself, but know that for heavy vector calculations you may want to use multi-threaded processing - maybe even on a GPU.